# Why is codigniter method called when header redirect should prevent it

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect, methods

I'm having a problem with Codeigniter and header redirects version 3.1.0

All my controllers are being extended from a controller which is called Page.
Page is extended from CI_Controller.

In the constructor method of the Page controller, I load the model M_login.
Then I check by calling a method from the M_login model if the user is logged in.

The structure I use:

```
/user  = folder inside of application/controllers
/modules = controller located inside folder user which extends Page controller
/view = method located inside controller class modules
/1 = parameter
```

Now the problem: When I call for example the URL domain.com/user/modules/view/1.

It triggers the controller Modules and executes the method View.
However this controller extends Page so first thing that should happen is to check if the user is logged in because it is in the constructor of the Page controller. If the user is not logged in, it should do a header redirect to the /login page.

However in my case it does run the method from the M_login model in the Page controller but also executes the View method from the Modules controller which then shows me errors so the header redirect is prevented from redirecting the user.

Can anybody tell me why the method View is still being executed despite the check if the user is logged in or not in the constructor of the Page controller which is called first.

I have now run into a brick wall and can't get my mind around it why. All the help would be appreciated. If you guys need more information then let me know.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Ok. As you say **Now the problem: When I call for example the URL domain.com/user/modules/view/1**, I can figure, that you're using normal CodeIgniter Framework.

> Reason I trigger it is, Normal Codeigniter framework doesn't allow you to use a folder inside the controller.

But you can use [**HMVC Codeigniter 3**](https://github.com/Abdulla-nilam/ci3-hmvc) which suites you.

**Or Else**

You can use route to modify your URL `/user/modules/view/1` like this